# how to Get DAG Files From A GitHub Repository?

Tags: github, airflow, azure-aks, bitnami

i'm trying to deploy a airflow on azure kubernetes services and loading DAG from GitHub  by using this command :

```
helm install airflow bitnami/airflow -n d --set git.dags.enabled=true --set git.dags.repositories[0].repository=https://github.com/lazkamal/aiflow_dags.git --set git.dags.repositories[0].name=ayyoub-repo --set git.dags.repositories[0].branch=main
```

but a get this error :

```
Error: template: airflow/templates/worker/statefulset.yaml:72:12: executing "airflow/templates/worker/statefulset.yaml" at <include "airflow.git.containers.clone" .>: error calling include: template: airflow/templates/_git_helpers.tpl:79:14: executing "airflow.git.containers.clone" at <.Values.containerSecurityContext.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [link](https://github.com/rolanddb/airflow-on-kubernetes)

There are several ways to deploy your DAG files when running Airflow on Kubernetes.

1. git-sync
2. Persistent Volume
3. Embedding in Docker container